# Is concatenating parameters with wildcards safe in stored procs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-injection

Is concatenating parameter values with % in stored procedures safe from SQL injection?

I have a stored procedure that allows the user to do searches for records that contain the given value in the columns of a table:

```
CREATE PROC sp_Search
@SearchValue NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ColumnA LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%' OR ColumnB LIKE '%' + @SearchValue + '%'
END
```

Comment: Yes. You are just comparing a value. Problem is when you try to create a dinamic sql.

Comment: Two things I would recommend though. Don't add the sp_ prefix. Either choose a different prefix or drop them altogether (my preference). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix The second thing is you have a leading wildcard which renders your query nonSARGable and no amount of indexing is going to help performance. If it is at all possible to avoid the leading wildcard you should.

Comment: Another question is how big is TableA and how do you try to search, remember that '%term%' is not [SARG-able](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Answer (score 0):

can you do ?

```
   CHARINDEX(@SearchValue, [COLUMNA]) > 0 
OR CHARINDEX(@SearchValue, [COLUMNB]) > 0
```

Comment: This is also nonSARGable and will force scans no matter what you do.